# Windows 10 Pro 1709 update to 1803, 1809 or 1903?

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates, windows-10-v1703

I am using Windows 10 Pro 1709 (OS build 16299.1087).

The update settings are as follows:

- "Semi-Annual Channel"
- 365 days delay of feature updates
- 30 days delay of quality updates

Now Windows has downloaded update 1803 x64 2019-07B and wants to install it by restart. However, I have postponed this so far.

Since I use my PC professionally I want a stable running system.

I know that there quality and stability issues with 1803 and 1809. So my question is: Should I update to 1803, 1809 or 1903 to get the most stable system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using Windows 10 Pro 1709 (OS build 16299.1087).

Windows 10 version 1709 End of Service (EOS) date was back on April 9, 2019.  So if you want a stable system you should immediately upgrade to one of the supported versions.  Windows 10 version 1803 will reach End of Service on November 12, 2019.

Windows 10 version 1809 and Windows 10 version 1903 will each End of Service on May 12, 2020 and December 8, 2020 respectfully.  The next feature update (19H2) will be a cumulative update for 1903.  This likely will result in an extension of the End of Service date to 1903 more than likely.

[image]

> Since I use my PC professionally I want a stable running system.

Windows 10 version 1809 and Windows 10 version 1903 are both considered stable.  The majority of the issues that were blocking users from 1903 have actually been resolved.  Most issues that exist on Windows 10 version 1903 also are also a problem for Windows 10 version 1809 (outside issues specific to Windows Sandbox).

[image]

[image]

> I know that there quality and stability issues with 1803 and 1809. So
>   my question is: Should I update to 1803, 1809 or 1903 to get the most
>   stable system?

Those stability issues have been resolved for months.  [Windows 10 version 1709](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1709) has numerous issues that are open currently, so it's not like that particular version of Windows 10, isn't without it's own flaws.  At the end of the day, most Windows 10 issues, apply the majority of the features.  It's only when an issue is specific to a feature, that only exists within a single Windows 10 version, is a feature release affected by that issue.

[image]

> I plan to go for 1809. As I mentioned in my question the system already downloaded 1803. How do I avoid the installation of 1803 and go directly to 1809?

You should use the Disk Cleanup tool to cleanup the temporary files, then download a Windows 10 1809 ISO, and perform the upgrade to Windows 10 1809 by mounting the image within Windows.

Relevant Information:

- [Windows 10, version 1903 and Windows Server, version 1903](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903)
- [Windows 10, version 1809 and Windows Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1809-and-windows-server-2019)

Answer (score 1):

*In theory* your current settings will be delaying updates to a point where there should not be any stability or quality issues. All being well you will have a years worth of quality issues in that version fixed.

- If you want latest with potential teething troubles then go for 1903.
- 1809 has been out for more than 6 months so there should no longer be any show-stopping bugs or errors, everything *should* just work
- your current settings are postponing feature updates for 1 year and as a result you are offered 1803. This version *should* be solid, by now well tested and fairly mature.
  The version number of `1803 x64 2019-07B` suggests that it is downloading it with all relevant updates to July 2019, meaning you are getting all the fixes without the problems of a newer "feature" update such as 1809 or 1903.

If you want best stability and least chance of issues then let it install the version it is proposing.

If you want to live on the edge then go for something newer.

If your system is mission critical and you have no backups then you want stability. If you want features but can tolerate a bit of risk then you want the latest.

Comment: I just read that the support for 1803 will end in September. So I plan to go for 1809. As I mentioned in my question the system already downloaded 1803. How do I avoid the installation of 1803 and go directly to 1809?

Answer (score 0):

These major build releases (e.g. 1803, 1809, 1903) are the stable releases. If you want unstable, you get the insider builds. But these are regular builds, and are all stable. Go with 1903 just because it's the most up to date stable.

Comment: OP is probably referring to the various problems experienced by early adopters of the 1809 and 1903 releases. These problems included deletion of files from OneDrive, and various other software, hardware or driver issues. That the "major" releases are *meant* to be stable is not in question, but they have been far from stable and "high quality" at release.

Comment: See https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-october-2018-update-problems-complaints and more generally https://www.google.com/search?q=1809+update+issues

Comment: Weren't most/all of those problems solved with updates after, and are now installed with the release? Worst case scenario, as long as user3384674 updates again after the feature update, they'd be fine.

Comment: @udlp - They were solved.  Everyone forgets all the issues 1507 and 1511 had when they were released.